# Dell laptop: Screen damage issue

Tags: display

I accidentally hit my laptop side last month then opening it in the morning. A black line started to appear then it got bigger over a week then after a month or so it slowly turned violet then some portions of the line started vanishing. 
I didn't do anything and it feels weird and I'm afraid that my laptop won't work after all the remaining violet line disappears.

Please can someone tell me why this is happening?

Comment: `I accidentally hit my laptop side last month` - `Please can someone tell me why this is happening?` - I think you explained the cause in your question. (On a side note, you might want to get an external display, if the line keeps getting bigger as you say it does).

Comment: the line has already stop spreading through out the screen and as i have notice the black line is slowly changing into violet color line and it is fading now and the screen only has very violet line which is fading also like what happened to the other line

Comment: I don't know what happened but the laptop seems fixing itself but my main issue is what if the violet line fades entirely I'm afraid that my screen won't function after it happens

Answer (score 0):

The [LCD (liquid crystal display)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liquid-crystal_display) has a layer of liquid that was sealed between two transparent plates. It's no longer sealed, and oozing out - perhaps into circuitry.

You have a few choices to continue using it.

- As @Zackary suggests, buy a separate display.
- Get a replacement display and have it installed.
- Use the laptop as a server, where no display is needed.